# Ternary operator inside render is not behaving correctly -react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, rendering

To be honest I am fairly new to react , I was trying to render list items with selected item class selector based on some condition.

I tried below

```
class AddEdit extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                      sections:[
                                  { name: 'address', label: 'Address', completed:'100',active:true},
                                  { name: 'description', label: 'Description', completed:'100',active:false},
                                  { name: 'sellers', label: 'Sellers', completed:'100',active:false},
                                  { name: 'solicitors', label: 'Solicitors', completed:'100',active:false},
                                  { name: 'listing_details', label: 'Listing Deatils', completed:'100',active:false},
                                  { name: 'library', label: 'Library', completed:'100',active:false},
                                  { name: 'reports', label: 'Reports', completed:'100',active:false}
                                ]
                    };
    }
```

Then I iterated like below'

```
render() {
        return (
          <div> 
                         <ul className="component-wrapper-item">

                           {this.state.sections.map(section =>
                               {section.active ? (
                                                    <li class="component-wrapper-item-selected">
                                                        <div className='component-item-label-selected'>&nbsp;{section.label}</div>
                                                     </li>
                                                    )
                                                  :  (
                                                       <li class="component-wrapper-item">
                                                           <div className='component-item-label'>{section.label}</div>
                                                        </li>
                                                     )

                                }
                           )}

                         </ul>


              </div>
        );
    }
```

It is not showing the list items after including the above logic, any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget put `return`. Also you need to put `key` attribute

```
render() {
        return (
          <div> 
               <ul className="component-wrapper-item">

                  {this.state.sections.map(section =>
                       { return section.active ? (
                            <li key={section.label} class="component-wrapper-item-selected">
                                  <div className='component-item-label-selected'>&nbsp;{section.label}</div>
                             </li>
                           )
                           :  (
                            <li  class="component-wrapper-item">
                              <div className='component-item-label'>{section.label}</div>
                            </li>
                          )

                       }
                    )}

                </ul>

              </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Is this not a typo mistake?

Comment: Thanks , actually my eyes are still not react friendly :)

Comment: @sumit sorry to say but the mistake here has nothing to do with react. Its an ES6 feature

Comment: @Rajesh : true.. I am very new to front end world

Comment: @Rajesh you can say it as a typo mistake.

Comment: @Ved in such cases, please chose to close question as a typographical question. You should use the privileges SO has provided to keep the portal clean.

Comment: IMO it will still help to someone who is not familiar with ECMA 6 syntax

Comment: @Rajesh I also thought to put just comment for the mistake. But thought it may not help OP as `return` need to be placed at correct place and also OP reputation is good. So added answer.

Comment: @sumit yup.  It worked for you. Hope you got your mistake.

Comment: @Ved *OP reputation is good* does not matter. We all learn new things and we will be beginners at it. *it may not help OP* the best way is to point out mistake and give link to docs. That will give more information. Also by no means I'm judging anyone's level. Point is a typographical question will not add much to portal as its unlikely anyone will repeat the same mistake. So a comment should be enough and then OP can delete the post to avoid unnecessary comments/votes.

Answer (score 1):

When you wrap the return value in an arrow function with `{}` you must write  `return` to return it.

Comment: You can just delete the curly brackets